# SHOULD I USE steady or steadily?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

We experienced problems meeting demand and sales fell sharply in November and remained STEADY / STEADILY at 39,000 in December.

Comment: The specifics of the question don't really matter here. If you work on learning how to distinguish the situations when you need to use an adjective from those when you need to use an adverb, you'll be able to figure out this and all similar questions!

Answer (score 0):

Something remains or is steady. steady is an adjective.

Prices rise or fall steadily. The adverb steadily modifies a transitive verb.

This answer does not cover the case of adverb modifying adjectives since it that is  not part of the question but can be looked up.

Comment: Round here the temperatures have remained stubbornly (or steadily) below zero degrees C.

Comment: Or obstinately, maybe?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey For every example, I can't point out every single point such as adverbs modifying nouns.

Comment: The donkey has remained stubborn, despite attempts to bribe it with vegetables.

Comment: @StuartF Yeah, the donkey balked stubbornly